# PHP / MySQL Order By Date & Random

Tags: php, mysql, random

I use this code to get my results from a database using PHP:

```
$get_article_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 8";
$get_article_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_article_sql);
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_article_res)){
...
}
```

However, what I really want to do is to randomise the results - So, I get the latest 8 articles and then randomise these results - Kind of like:

```
$get_article_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY added DESC RAND() LIMIT 8";
```

Obviously this gives a fetch error but is there any actual way of doing this?

Comment: Add the result to an `array`, use `shuffle()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php then output them

Answer (score 3):

You can either shuffle them in PHP, which is probably faster, by using `shuffle($array)` once you have all the results, or you can use a query but then you'd have to basically use a subquery to fetch the total results inside a query that shuffles the rest.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 8 ) ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Thanks but this still gives me an error `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C...`

Comment: You´ll have to find the actual sql error, otherwise we cannot help. This just signals that the query failed, but it does not show why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM articles order by article_id DESC LIMIT 8) `table` ORDER BY RAND()"
```

Comment: There's a ) too many - And this gives me an error if I remove it

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After testing, it would not randomize after first query. The more I thought about it, seems that you want to pull random records and then `ORDER BY added`? In this case a subquery is required.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8) AS random 
ORDER BY added DESC;
```

**[New SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/135903/1)**

Comment: @Strawberry - I made a fiddle :D